# htaccess language detection returns in endless redirects - who finds the bug?

Tags: .htaccess, language-detection

i have a [survey community](http://community.netigate.net/) with 3 languages using the WPML plugin for Wordpress to handle the languages. unfortunately the language detection works only via php. i want to use htaccess, since it is faster and the user wouldn't notice a delay.

The setup is the following:

```
community.netigate.net/ (English, International)

community.netigate.net/de/ (German)

community.netigate.net/sv/ (Swedish)
```

i tried different approaches and found the best one to be the one at

> http://tech-blog.borychowski.com/index.php/2009/03/htaccess/redirect-according-to-browser-language-mod-rewrite-and-http_accept_language/

Since most users are Germans or Swedes, I want "English" only to be the standard fallback language. the setup could be like this:

> CHECK IF Language is Swedish, THEN redirect to swedish subpage
>     CHECK IF language is German, THEN redirect to German subpage
>     ELSE use English as Fallback

**Unfortunately the solution below ends up in endless redirects? Did I miss something?**

```
## Language Detection

#The 'Accept-Language' header starts with 'sv'
#and the test is case-insensitive ([NC])

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^sv [NC]

#Redirect user to /sv/hauptseite address
#sending 301 (Moved Permanently) HTTP status code

RewriteRule ^$ /sv/ [L,R=301]

#The 'Accept-Language' header starts with 'de'
#and the test is case-insensitive ([NC])

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^de [NC]

#Redirect user to /de/hauptseite address
#sending 301 (Moved Permanently) HTTP status code

RewriteRule ^$ /de/ [L,R=301]

#For every other language (including English :)) use English

RewriteRule ^$ / [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add another rewrite condition that checks if redirection has already taken place

```
## Language Detection

#The 'Accept-Language' header starts with 'sv'
#and the test is case-insensitive ([NC])

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^sv [NC]

#If not already redirected
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/sv/ [NC]    # ADDED

#Redirect user to /sv/hauptseite address
#sending 301 (Moved Permanently) HTTP status code

RewriteRule ^$ /sv/ [L,R=301]

#The 'Accept-Language' header starts with 'de'
#and the test is case-insensitive ([NC])

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^de [NC]

#If not already redirected
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/de/ [NC]    # ADDED

#Redirect user to /de/hauptseite address
#sending 301 (Moved Permanently) HTTP status code

RewriteRule ^$ /de/ [L,R=301]

#For every other language (including English :)) use English

RewriteRule ^$ - [L]    # MODIFIED
```

Comment: wow, thanks. should have thought about that the fallback just needs to go to the standard version and doesn't need are redirect.

how would you deal with similar languages? there are different swedish or german versions like

de
de-de
de-at
de-ch

same with swedish

sv
sv-se
...


since i havent them in my rewrite rules now, how would i deal with them?

Comment: @Boxhorn It's simple. Do you want `sv` or `sv-se` etc. all to redirect to `/sv/` or it should include the region like `/sv-se/` when redirecting?

Comment: well, the best would be to group the redirects like

sv
sv-se
sv-fi

... go to homepage.com/se/

and

de
de-at
de-ch
...

go to homepage.com/de

Comment: I believe this should be happening already because a rule like `^en` would match both `en` and `en-US` because it says `starts with 'en'`. The complete `Accept-Language` header that a browser sends is like `en-US;en;q=0.5`. So, it should already be working.

Answer (score 0):

This line here:

```
#For every other language (including English :)) use English
RewriteRule ^$ / [L,R=301]
```

Is redirecting `/` back to `/`, causing the redirect loop. You don't need this line at all.